# How do you re-run 'Spelling and Grammer' after changing a setting in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, spell-check

I have a document of 10 pages in Word (2016 Mac). I want to detect Oxford commas in the document. To do so, I turned on the 'detect Oxford comma' setting in Preferences > Spelling and Grammer > Settings.

When I type a new sentence it detects Oxford commas, but it does not detect them in sentences I'd written before changing the setting. E.g. see the picture below - the top line was written after changing the setting and detects the comma, but the bottom had been written before and shows Word doesn't detect the comma.

I've tried running Spelling and Grammer, but tells me "Spelling and grammar check is complete."

[image]

Comment: Try highlighting (selecting) the entire text and then check Spelling and Grammar again.

Comment: Thanks, just tried, same message "Spelling and grammar check is complete."

Comment: Check your speling! ooops...

Comment: Version of Word? Word 2013 or earlier? Does your Word use the Editor or the legacy spelling check dialog? See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/classic-spell-check-dialog-macro-to-use-to-get/a53fff0c-f15d-4150-95d6-1724c6ddca91.

Comment: I assume that you have tried closing Word and reopening.

Comment: Using Word for Mac 2016 (16.32) - I'll update the description. Yes I'd tried closing and reopening. I'd ideally like to try to solve using build in options rather than fiddling with macros but will look into the link, thanks.

Comment: I've also tried copy pasting the entire document into a new document. Weirdly, it detects some Oxford commas but not all of them. There seems to be an inconsistancy with how it runs it's spell checker through the doc.

Comment: This might be part of a broader spelling inconsistancy problem. I've tried doing Tools > Uncheck Do not check spelling or grammar, but some sentences were still immune to spelling and grammer (unless retyped by hand). https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-spell-check-inconsistent-missing-errors/e489f982-ff74-449d-9fd1-c97c5fbda5c0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows version on Word, go to Word>Options, which in current versions of Word is under the File tab on the Ribbon. In the Options dialog, choose Proofing from the left column and locate the "When correcting spelling and grammar Word" group of controls. Use the Recheck Document button in this group. It will reset the spelling and grammar function so previously ignored words will now be checked.

If you are using a Mac version on Word, on the Menu Bar at the top of the window, choose Tools > Spelling and Grammar and you'll see the Reset button on the contextual menu.

Comment: Thanks I gave this a shot, but it still doesn't get all of them - I get the same things as in the screenshot above where it fails to detects the oxford comma in the original sentence (below), but detects it if it's copied and pasted or re-written.